# How to get text from all TextViews RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

First of all sorry for the language. I have a `RecyclerView` with items. I have a `checkbox` in each item. I have `onCheckedChangeListener` inside `RecyclerAdapter`.

When I check 4 `checkboxes` I need to disable the remaining. So how can I get an access for them? I can do it when on create Recycler by checking how many items are selected. But can't find how to get access for every `checkbox` in `onCheckedChange` method. [Screenshot example](https://ibb.co/28jGSc2)

```
public class EditAtributesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EditAtributesAdapter.EditAtributesViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<AtributeEditItem> mEditAtributeList;
    DBHelper dbHelper;


    public static class EditAtributesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView mImageView;
        public CheckBox mCheckBox;

        public EditAtributesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.edit_atribute_icon);
            mCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.enabledAtribute);
        }
    }


    public EditAtributesAdapter(ArrayList<AtributeEditItem> editAtributeList){
        mEditAtributeList = editAtributeList;
    }

    @Override
    public EditAtributesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.atribute_edit_item, parent, false);
        final Context forClickCTX = parent.getContext();
        final EditAtributesViewHolder eavh = new EditAtributesViewHolder(v);


        eavh.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                int pos = eavh.getAdapterPosition();
                // System.out.println("Hello, you clicked: " + mEditAtributeList.get(pos).getName());
                dbHelper = new DBHelper(forClickCTX);
                try {
                    dbHelper.createDataBase();}
                catch (IOException ioe) {
                    throw new Error("Не удалось создать базу данных");}
                try {
                    dbHelper.openDataBase();}
                catch (SQLException sqle) {
                    throw sqle;}


                int countSelected = 0;
                if (countSelected == 0){
                    Cursor cursor = null;
                    try {
                        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                        cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_TASKS, null, "id = " + mEditAtributeList.get(pos).getTask_id(), null, null, null, null);
                        while (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            String ids = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DBHelper.TASK_ATRIBUTE_ID));
                            String[] parts = ids.split(",");
                            int[] ints = new int[parts.length];
                            for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                                ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
                            }
                            countSelected = ints.length;
                        }
                    } finally {
                        if (cursor != null)
                            cursor.close();
                    }
                    if(countSelected>=5){
                        if(!eavh.mCheckBox.isChecked())
                            eavh.mCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
                        else
                            eavh.mCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                    else
                        eavh.mCheckBox.setEnabled(true);

            }
     //here is saving new status to db ( a lot of code)
    });
        return eavh;
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(EditAtributesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        AtributeEditItem currentItem = mEditAtributeList.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImage());
        holder.mCheckBox.setText(currentItem.getName());
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(currentItem.isSelected());

        int countSelected = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < mEditAtributeList.size() ; i++){
            if(mEditAtributeList.get(i).isSelected())
                countSelected++;
        }
        if(countSelected>=5){
            if(!holder.mCheckBox.isChecked())
                holder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(false);
            else
                holder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
            holder.mCheckBox.setEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mEditAtributeList.size();
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your adapter and viewholder are actually doing too much, but for a small list you can probably get away with it.  Calling the sqldatabse like this onclick can be a bit awkward, i am not sure, but i think you are blocking the main thread with this which means you may notice that onclick slightly freezes your app.

But the simplest way disable the items in your recyclerview is to update the items in your

```
private ArrayList<AtributeEditItem> mEditAtributeList
```

and call

```
notifyDataSetChanged()
```

on the adapter, as you can then derive the state based on the data